# Restore git submodules from .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a folder, which was a git repo. It contains some files and .gitmodules file. Now, when I do `git init` and then `git submodule init`, the latter command output is nothing. How can I help git to see submodules, defined in .gitmodules file without running `git submodule add` by hand again?

Update:
this is my .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "vim-pathogen"]
    path = vim-pathogen
    url = git://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen.git
[submodule "bundle/python-mode"]
    path = bundle/python-mode
    url = git://github.com/klen/python-mode.git
[submodule "bundle/vim-fugitive"]
    path = bundle/vim-fugitive
    url = git://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive.git
[submodule "bundle/ctrlp.vim"]
    path = bundle/ctrlp.vim
    url = git://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git
[submodule "bundle/vim-tomorrow-theme"]
    path = bundle/vim-tomorrow-theme
    url = git://github.com/chriskempson/vim-tomorrow-theme.git
```

and here is listing of this dir:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 evgeniuz 100 4096 июня  29 12:06 .
drwx------ 60 evgeniuz 100 4096 июня  29 11:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 evgeniuz 100 4096 июня  29 10:03 autoload
drwxr-xr-x  7 evgeniuz 100 4096 июня  29 12:13 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 evgeniuz 100  542 июня  29 11:45 .gitmodules
-rw-r--r--  1 evgeniuz 100  243 июня  29 11:18 .vimrc
```

so, definitely, it is in top level. the git directory is not changed, only `git init` is done

Comment: Are the submodules already present, in the sense that if you change into any submodule directory there are files present, and `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` gives you the submodule rather than "supermodule" directory?

Comment: no, submodule dirs are not present. imagine this folder is completely empty with just `.gitmodules` file

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is - I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`git submodule init` only considers submodules that already are in the index (i.e. "staged") for initialization.  I would write a short script that parses `.gitmodules`, and for each `url` and `path` pair runs:

```
git submodule add <url> <path>
```

For example, you could use the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' |
    while read path_key local_path
    do
        url_key=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\.path/.url/')
        url=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "$url_key")
        git submodule add $url $local_path
    done
```

This is based on how the [`git-submodule.sh` script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a3fbb2350dcd2d843d1d90b663521222aceb25fe/git-submodule.sh#L132) itself parses the `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: do you mean `git submodule update --init`? all of these commands fail silently. It looks like git doesn't see modules defined only in `.gitmodules`

Comment: After the `git submodule init`, do you see any output from `git config --list | grep submodule`?  (As the documentation says, `git submodule init` should "Initialize the submodules, i.e. register each submodule name and url found in .gitmodules into `.git/config`".)

Comment: no, nothing. `git config --list` gives only standard values, no mention of submodules

Comment: @Shark: that's strange - could you update your question with the contents of your `.gitmodules` file?  Also, is your `.gitmodules` file definitely at the top level of your repository, rather than a subdirectory?

Comment: @Shark: yeah, me too - and I may well be missing something obvious!  However, I think the idea of initializing from `.gitmodules` is that it will have been committed in the same commit (or close to the same commit) as one that added the submodules to the tree, so having only `.gitmodules`, but no submodules in the index, is an unusual situation to be in.

Comment: ```git submodule update --init -f``` - will fork submodules to it`s dir`s permomently.

Comment: One of the problems here is that because the original `.git` is not available, you don't know which commit-id the submodule was pinned to, this makes it difficult to acquire the exact revision of the submodule that you had in the original repository.

Comment: Has anyone got a solution for parsing the branch in the `.gitmodules` file and adding the submodule using the correct branch?

Comment: Unfortunately, if the submodule contains spaces like after `git submodule add URL 'path with spaces'` this solution fails.  Perhaps try something like `git config -f .gitmodules -z --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' | sed -z 's/\n.*$//' | tr '\0' '\n' | while read keys; ..`

Comment: If some submodules are already in the index, the script will exit. To avoid that: git submodule add $url $path || true

Answer (score 16):

Expanding on @Mark Longair's answer, I wrote a bash script to automate steps 2 & 3 of the following process:

1. Clone a 'boilerplate' repo to begin a new project
2. Remove the .git folder and re-initialize as a new repo
3. Re-initialize the submodules, prompting for input before deleting folders

---

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
rm -rf .git
git init

git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' > tempfile

while read -u 3 path_key path
do
    url_key=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\.path/.url/')
    url=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "$url_key")

    read -p "Are you sure you want to delete $path and re-initialize as a new submodule? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) rm -rf $path; git submodule add $url $path; echo "$path has been initialized";;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac

done 3<tempfile

rm tempfile
```

*Note: the submodules will be checked out at the tip of their master branch instead of the same commit as the boilerplate repo, so you'll need to do that manually.*

Piping the output from git config into the read loop was causing problems with the prompt for input, so it outputs it to a temp file instead. Any improvements on my first bash script would be very welcome :)

---

Big thanks to Mark, https://stackoverflow.com/a/226724/193494, [bash: nested interactive read within a loop that's also using read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11704353/193494), and tnettenba @ chat.freenode.net for helping me arrive at this solution!

Answer (score 10):

Extending excellent @Mark Longair's answer to add submodule respecting branch and repo name.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' |
    while read path_key path
    do
        name=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\submodule\.\(.*\)\.path/\1/')
        url_key=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\.path/.url/')
        branch_key=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\.path/.branch/')
        url=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "$url_key")
        branch=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "$branch_key" || echo "master")
        git submodule add -b $branch --name $name $url $path || continue
    done
```

Comment: This worked great, however it also duplicated each entry in the .gitmodules file which needs some manual cleanup after the fact.

Answer (score 5):

An updated version of the script by @mark-longair . This one also supports branches, handles the case where some of the submodules already exist in `.git/config`, and when necessary backs up existing directories of the same name as the submodule paths.

```
git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' |
    while read path_key path
    do
        url_key=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\.path/.url/');
        branch_key=$(echo $path_key | sed 's/\.path/.branch/');
        # If the url_key doesn't yet exist then backup up the existing
        # directory if necessary and add the submodule
        if [ ! $(git config --get "$url_key") ]; then
            if [ -d "$path" ] && [ ! $(git config --get "$url_key") ]; then
                mv "$path" "$path""_backup_""$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')";
            fi;
            url=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "$url_key");
            # If a branch is specified then use that one, otherwise
            # default to master
            branch=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "$branch_key");
            if [ ! "$branch" ]; then branch="master"; fi;
            git submodule add -f -b "$branch" "$url" "$path";
        fi;
    done;

# In case the submodule exists in .git/config but the url is out of date

git submodule sync;

# Now actually pull all the modules. I used to use this...
#
# git submodule update --init --remote --force --recursive
# ...but the submodules would check out in detached HEAD state and I 
# didn't like that, so now I do this...

git submodule foreach --recursive 'git checkout $(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch || echo master)';
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. `git submodule init` was failing silently.

When I did:

`git submodule add <url> <path>`

I got:

`The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files: ...`

I'm thinking that .gitignore(d) paths might be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I'm so surprised to see so many scripts for a very simple action and unfortunately I haven't found any tool or ready for use command. The only software so far which allows to restore it - is Gitkraken. Check here: https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/submodules/

Comment: Actually I have found one: `npx @iclare/ksync .gitmodules . --nobackup`

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while, but I want to share this version that calls `git config` only once, doesn't requires a script and also handles branches:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\.' | perl -lane'
$conf{$F[0]} = $F[1]}{
@mods = map {s,\.path$,,; $_} grep {/\.path$/} keys(%conf);
sub expand{$i = shift; map {$conf{$i . $_}} qw(.path .url .branch)}
for $i (@mods){
    ($path, $url, $branch) = expand($i);
    print(qq{rm -rf $path});
    print(qq{git submodule add -b $branch $url $path});
}
'
```

The only side effect is the output of the commands, nothing gets executed, so you can audit before committing to them.

This works with a simple copy and paste at the console, but should be trivial to put in a shell script.

example output:

```
rm -rf third-party/dht
git submodule add -b post-0.25-transmission https://github.com/transmission/dht third-party/dht
rm -rf third-party/libutp
git submodule add -b post-3.3-transmission https://github.com/transmission/libutp third-party/libutp
rm -rf third-party/libb64
git submodule add -b post-1.2.1-transmission https://github.com/transmission/libb64 third-party/libb64
rm -rf third-party/libnatpmp
git submodule add -b post-20151025-transmission https://github.com/transmission/libnatpmp third-party/libnatpmp
rm -rf third-party/miniupnpc
git submodule add -b post-2.0.20170509-transmission https://github.com/transmission/miniupnpc third-party/miniupnpc
rm -rf third-party/libevent
git submodule add -b post-2.0.22-transmission https://github.com/transmission/libevent third-party/libevent
```

Answer (score 0):

For zsh users, try my function which has `DRY_RUN=1` support to see what commands will be ran and only uses `git` to parse the file instead of `sed`.

```
gsub_file() {(
  set -eu

  cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

  submodule_paths=(
    "${(@f)$(git config --file ./.gitmodules --get-regexp "path" | awk '{ print $2 }')}"
  )
  submodule_urls=(
    "${(@f)$(git config --file ./.gitmodules --get-regexp "url" | awk '{ print $2 }')}"
  )
  submodule_branches=(
    "${(@f)$(git config --file ./.gitmodules --get-regexp "branch" | awk '{ print $2 }')}"
  )

  sh_c() {
    echo + "$*"
    if [ "${DRY_RUN-}" ]; then
      return
    fi
    eval "$@"
  }

  for (( i=1; i <= ${#submodule_paths[@]}; i++ )) do
    p="${submodule_paths[$i]}"
    if [ -d "$p" ]; then
      continue
    fi

    url="${submodule_urls[$i]}"
    unset b
    if [ "${submodule_branches[$i]-}" ]; then
      b="-b ${submodule_branches[$i]}" 
    fi
    sh_c git submodule add "${b-}" "$url" "$p"
  done
)}
```