# bash: nested interactive read within a loop that's also using read

Tags: bash, while-loop, interactive

How does one code an interactive response in this while loop?

```
#!/bin/bash

shows=$(< ${HOME}/.get_iplayer/tv.cache)

# ...
# ... stuff with shows omitted ...
# ...

function print_show {
# ...
    return
}

while read -r line
do
    print_show "$line"

    read -n 1 -p "do stuff? [y/n] : " resp  # PROBLEM

# ...
# resp actions omitted
# ...

done <<< "$shows"
```

So a file is read, "processed" then the resulting line oriented data is used in a `while read` loop

But the read line within the while loop doesn't work as intended, that is it doesn't wait for the user response, presumably due to the `while read` context it is encapsulated by.

Could you please suggest how to fix this or an alternate mechanism?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've correctly identified that the cause is that within the

```
while ...; do ...; done <<< "$shows"
```

loop, stdin has been redirected, thus `read` is no longer reading from the keyboard.

You can solve this by using a file descriptor other than 0; for example,

```
while read -r -u 3 line; do ...; done 3<${HOME}/.get_iplayer/tv.cache
```

will use FD 3 for the file rather than FD 0, allowing the normal `read` (without `-u`) to use original stdin, or

```
while ...; do read -n 1 -p "do stuff? [y/n] : " -u 3 resp; done 3<&0 <<< "$shows"
```

to clone the original FD 0 to FD 3 before replacing FD 0 with your string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already reading the entire file into memory, read it into an array instead of a single string.

```
# Requires bash 4 or later
mapfile -t loop_input < $HOME/.get_iplayer/tv.cache

for line in "${loop_input[@]}"; do
    print_show "$line"
    read -n 1 -p "do stuff? [y/n] : " resp
done
```

---

If you still use an earlier version of bash, I'd still recommend reading the file
into an array instead of a single string, but it's less convenient.

```
declare -a loop_input
while read; do loop_input+=("$REPLY"); done

for line in "${loop_input[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

or, you can just not read the file all into memory:

```
while read -u 3 line; do
    ....
done 3< $HOME/.get_iplayer/tv.cache
```

Comment: Neat, though watch out that `mapfile` was added in Bash 4.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that to my tool kit.