# Write to the next empty line in an existing csv file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, unix, git-bash

I am writing a script wherein rather than writing over the existing data, I would like to write to the next empty line in the csv file.

Current Output

```
texta,2
textb,
filed1,field2,field3
1,abc,123
2,xyz,124
```

Expected Output

```
texta,2
textb,
filed1,field2,field3
1,abc,123
2,xyz,124
1,jkl,547
```

The current code which writes over the existing data in the file

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter file name"
read name
if [ condition ]
then
     #commands
else
     echo "Enter alphabets"
     read alpha
     echo "Enter number"
     read number
     echo "1,$alpha,$number" >> ${name}.csv
fi
```

Example input here `aplha = jkl` and `number = 547`

This will write over the entire data but I would like to write only to the next empty line each time the `if` condition fails. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks ok, since `>` truncate and `>>` append, maybe the file has carriage returns?

Comment: @Jetchisel True, my bad . While actually writing in bash i used `> `and over here `>>`  It does work

Comment: Your code lacks a loop to iterate the input lines. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308110/does-bash-support-doing-a-read-nested-within-a-read-loop) for nested `read`.