# Use a .gitmodules from another project

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I have a project "NewProject" that needs the same submodules than another project "OldProject".

Since I don't want to manually do the following manipulation in NewProject

 `git submodule add git@gitlab.me:my-submodule.git`

I hope that there is a way to re-use the `.gitmodules` file from OldProject

Here is what I tried for the moment:

- `cp OldProject/.gitmodules NewProject/.gitmodules` -> ok (wouaw)
- `git submodule init` -> nothing
- `git submodule update` -> nothing
- `git submodule update --init` -> nothing
- `git submodule sync` -> nothing
- `git submodule update --init --recursive` -> nothing

I've seen countless problems of people trying to change the url (or the name) of their submodule(s) but I don't think that this is similar, the new factor being that the NewProject git repository is vanilla (have no `.git/modules`).

So do you think there is a way to do what I intend to ?
and if yes, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr;

not possible -> workaround [via script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258737/restore-git-submodules-from-gitmodules/11258810#11258810)

### Details

Your problem is the missing `git submodule add` call. This is what adds the submodule configuration to your `.git/config` file, creates a folder for your submodule in `.git/modules`, adds a submodule entry to `.gitmodules` and creates a folder in your repository in which the submodule will be checked out. I could not find a way to initialize a submodule without having added it before. Even if you copy the folder, the `config` entry and the `.gitmodule` file, any `init`or `update` call fails.

To answer your question: I do not think there is a way to skip the `submodule add` call and just reuse your `.gitmodules` file.

EDIT: And, by the way, even a newly initialized git repository has a `.git/config` file.

EDIT2: What exactly is the reason to avoid calling `git submodule add`?

Comment: because there are +50 submodules and I didn't want to do it by hand :'(

Comment: and you are right about the `.git/config`, I'll update the question

Comment: Ouch. Yep, that's a good reason.

Comment: But well, you could write some crazy shell script parsing the other projects' `.gimodules` file and calling `git submodule add` for each of them...

Comment: [Look what I found!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11258810/7598462)

Comment: whaouw thank you. Could you add a "tl;dr; not possible -> workaround : script" in your response? and I'll accept your answer

Comment: oh yeah mark it as duplicate, works too ^^