# Add a list of submodules to the git

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have cloned a project and customized it. the project is using some extra projects as submodules. I have setup  mine git repository and push the main project there. but I did not add the submodules to mine git project.

I want to pull the submodules to my project. I know using following command  I can add submodules one by one :

> git submodule add `<sub-m url> <path>`

But they are a lot. is there another way to add them automatically and all together ? here is the list of submodules :

```
submodule "submodules/bcg729"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/bcg729.git
[submodule "submodules/bctoolbox"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/bctoolbox.git
[submodule "submodules/belcard"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/belcard.git
[submodule "belle-sip"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/belle-sip.git
[submodule "submodules/belr"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/belr.git
[submodule "submodules/bzrtp"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/bzrtp.git
[submodule "submodules/cmake-builder"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/linphone-cmake-builder.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/antlr3"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/antlr3.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/axmlrpc"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/axmlrpc.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/bv16-floatingpoint"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/bv16-floatingpoint.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/cunit"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/cunit.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/ffmpeg"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/ffmpeg.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/gsm"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/gsm.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/libmatroska"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/libmatroska-c.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/libupnp"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/libupnp.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/libvpx"]
    url = https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx
[submodule "submodules/externals/libxml2"]
    url = git://git.gnome.org/libxml2.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/mbedtls"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/mbedtls.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/opencore-amr"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/opencore-amr.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/openh264"]
    url = https://github.com/cisco/openh264
[submodule "submodules/externals/opus"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/opus.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/speex"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/speex.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/srtp"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/srtp.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/vo-amrwbenc"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/vo-amrwbenc.git
[submodule "submodules/externals/x264"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/x264.git
[submodule "submodules/linphone"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/linphone.git
[submodule "submodules/msamr"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/msamr.git
[submodule "submodules/mscodec2"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/mscodec2.git
[submodule "submodules/msopenh264"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/msopenh264.git
[submodule "submodules/mssilk"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/mssilk.git
[submodule "submodules/mswebrtc"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/mswebrtc.git
[submodule "submodules/msx264"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/msx264.git
[submodule "linphone"]
    url = git://git.linphone.org/linphone.git
```

Comment: that list is not in the `.gitmodules` file ? I just `git clone https://github.com/guardianproject/linphone-ios-secure` (which is a project with similar submodules to you), then `git submodule update --init` did the job

Comment: Yes, I am using Linphon android, But I  have  create a  git repository that it does not contain that submodules. I just want to work on mine code and I don't want to add submodules to my repository, I am looking for a way fetch the submodules locally when I cloned my project.

Comment: Actually I did a lot of work on the Linphone code then I added it to mine repository. after a while I am going to clone it on another device but The submodules are not exists, so I want find a way add them when somebody fetch mine code. I am not that much skilled in git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is such a way with git. However, you could just do a shell script that iterates your list and calls `git submodule add` on each of them, one by one.

---

Why just copying them to .gitmodules or to .git/index won't do the trick:

> The "git submodule add" command does a couple of things:
>
> - It clones the submodule under the current directory and by default checks out the master branch.
> - It adds the submodule's clone path to the ".gitmodules" file and adds this file to the index, ready to be committed.
> - It adds the submodule's current commit ID to the index, ready to be committed.

([source](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial))

So you would be missing the last step, and git submodule init/update expect the commit id to be already in place. That is why you need `git submodule add`.

Comment: I am going to test this, I will tell u the result , thanks

Comment: damned it seems you're right ! And that's a shame there is no command to add a group of repo all in oncem so @eis answer is the right one. You may have additionnal help from that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629822/is-it-possible-to-make-git-aware-of-an-existing-gitmodules-file/7656021#7656021

Comment: I have write a shell script to do that as you said. it solves my issue. but i wish there was another way do that by git itself. thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @eis suggestion, you have to create a script to make all the `git add` commands.

A way to do that is to create the `.gitmodules` containing your needs, then parse it with a script like this one:

```
iterator=1;
subpaths=$(git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp path | awk '{ print $2}');
subrepos=$(git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp url | awk '{ print $2}');
for path in $subpaths; do
  repo=$(echo "$subrepos"| sed $iterator'q;d');
  git submodule add $repo $path;
  let iterator++;
done
```