# Changing a submodule's remote and branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule that is using the wrong remote and the wrong branch. I have edited the `.gitmodules` file in the parent git repository so have the correct url (remote) and branch. However when I use any variation of `git submodule init`, `git submodule update`, `git reset --hard origin/branch`, etc. from within or outside of the submodule, at worst I get an error and at best I get a confirmation that the command succeeded with **no actual change to the code in the submodule's directory**.

Assuming my `.gitmodules` is configured correctly, how do I correctly update the submodule directory so that it shows code from the correct remote/branch combination?

**Update:** It appears that the "branch" attribute of the submodule configuration is ignored when performing an update.

Comment: It's ignored unless you use `--remote`, `--merge`, and/or `--rebase`.

Comment: @torek Thanks for responding but without more context I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Could you elaborate and perhaps give a specific example?

Comment: I don't like, and hence don't use, sobmodules, so I don't have any actual examples.  Check out `git help submodule` and search for `branch` though.  It's quite confusing, but it does say that `--remote` makes it act differently, and that update checks some additional settings in `submodule.<name>.update`.

Answer (score 1):

By [removing the submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule) and doing `git submodule add`, see for example [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37433705/365237). The issue there is not an exact duplicate but explains why just updating .gitmodules won't do the trick:

> The "git submodule add" command does a couple of things:
>
> - It clones the submodule under the current directory and by default checks out the master branch.
> - It adds the submodule's clone path to the ".gitmodules" file and adds this file to the index, ready to be committed.
> - It adds the submodule's current commit ID to the index, ready to be committed.
>
> So you would be missing the last step, and git submodule init/update expect the commit id to be already in place. That is why you need `git submodule add`.

Comment: This seems like a total hack. Based on your and @torek's resonses I am strongly considering abandoning submodules altogether. Maybe it's better to just `.gitignore` the subdirectory and use a traditional repository. My build scripts can update these as needed.

Comment: @Jake I don't think removing and adding a submodule conf qualifies as a hack, but I agree that there are a lot of things with submodules that do feel like hackish, and I'm not a big fan of functionality either. Some say subtrees are a better option, I personally prefer just using separate repositories.

Comment: Maybe "hack" is the wrong word but this is analogous to "turn it off and on again" and isn't indicative of a fully implemented feature.

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same thing you'd do with a regular git remote - you remove the old one and add a new one. But I'm not really disagreeing you on the general point.