# How to convert a list of git repository into single repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have multiple git repository. How can I convert this as a Single repository. Is there any possible to do this?

Repositories:

1. module_1.git
2. module_2.git
3. module_3.git
4. module_4.git
5. module_5.git

I want the above list of repository into a single repository as **Modules.git**. All of the above converted into directories of **Modules** repository.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a list of submodules to the git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432536/add-a-list-of-submodules-to-the-git)

Comment: it depends on what you want to do with the history of each repository

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to "convert" it. You basically just have to create new repository that will contain all needed content.

1. Create new empty local Git repository.
2. Move all needed files there and commit them.
3. Push local repository into GitLab.

More details here:
[GitLab - Push to create new project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project)